# Error while running a lambda function to change all items in a series meeting certain conditions; the error returns the first item in series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, series

I have a series from the Titanic data frame that divides the passangers by first, second and third class. The `.unique_values()` returned are `['1', '2', '3', '?']`. I would like to change the '?' value to 'Unknown'.

I tried running the following code:

```
df['Pclass'] = df['Pclass'].map(lambda x: 'Unknown' if (df['Pclass'][x] == '?') else df['Pclass'][x])
```

I got the following error:

'3'

This happens to be the first item in the series when I run `df['Pclass'][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe in this form:

```
  Pclass
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      ?
```

you have to use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [1, 2, 3, "?"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Pclass'])

df['Pclass'] = df['Pclass'].apply(lambda x: 'Unknown' if x == '?' else x)
print(df)
```

output will be:

```
    Pclass
0        1
1        2
2        3
3  Unknown
```